# Should I use two seperate projects for frontend/backend in addition with API or merge them to one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I have a few questions which I'd appreciate to have some answers on.

So I've created a backend node server with express & mongo which is running specific tasks on the net and saves it in the database in a loop. I've also added an admin page with express & bootstrap. And that works fine. What I needed then was a frontend page - for this I chose VueJS. I started that project seperate for multiple reasons. I felt that this would be easier to get started, since I didn't have any frontend framework experience before and the backend project was written in typescript and I'd rather use normal es6 JS for now.

Right now - the site has already made some pretty decent progress and is at the point where I need to establish connection with the database and also use some of the already implemented functions in the backend project.

And this created the question:

- Should I create new functions and/or create and use API's? Would there be any problem with the mongodb in the form of accessing and writing to it by two different processes? Would there be security issues if I'd create "public" apis from my already existing backend logic? (Haven't written any apis yet.)
- Or should I use the time and import the frontend project into the backend (meaning also either translating new to typescript or switching to normal ES6 JS)? Would this be a security risk since I'd rather not have the backend logic in my frontend site.

I appreciate any answer to that!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a question of can you afford to run two servers? separating your front end from your back end is actually a good move considering all things microservices since it allows you to scale these things separately for future purposes. Like your backend needing more resources once you start catering to mobile user as well or once you get more api calls, while your front end server need only serve the ui and assets, nothing more. Though the clear downside is the increase in costs since you do need to run two servers instead of one, something that is difficult when you are just starting out

---

**Should I create new functions and/or create and use API's?**

For your backend? Yes. APIs are the way to do things now in the webspace as it future proofs you and allows a more controlled and uniform way to access your backend(everything goes through the api). So if your front end isnt accessing your database through the APIs yet, i suggest you refactor them to do so.

For your concerns about mongo, im pretty sure mongo already has features in place to avoid deadlocks.

As for security of your API, I suggest checking out [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

---

**should I use the time and import the frontend project into the backend**

should you go this path instead due to cost concerns, i would suggest rewriting one of the codebase to comply with the other for uniformity's sake, though do that at your leisure(we can't have you wasting all your precious time rewriting code that already works just fine). this isnt really that much of a security issue since backend code isnt being sent to the front end for all your users to see

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. I've went for seperate backend and frontend. I already got the api in place - now I only need to secure it through JWT. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying I've never used Vue. However, whenever I use react, I always make separate projects for the front end and the back end. I find it's 'cleaner' to keep the two separate.

I see no reason for you to transcribe your entire project from typescript. Simply have your frontend make requests to your backend.

If you're looking to brush up on your web security, I recommend you look into the [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/About_The_Open_Web_Application_Security_Project).

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. I've went for seperate backend and frontend. I already got the api in place - now I only need to secure it through JWT. Thank you :)